# Ubuntu 18.04 Grub 2 Installation error on fresh install

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

As the title states I am getting a grub 2 installation error during a fresh install of 18.04 onto a 960 evo 1tb drive.

**System Specs:**

MSI Pro Gaming x470

Ryzen 1800x

Gigabyte Windforce Gtx 1070

16gb corsair lpx @ 2933MHz

**Steps Taken:**

Secure Boot Disabled

Fast Boot Disabled

UEFI Boot mode only

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a solution to the issue for those that are in the same boat as me.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS then proceeded to upgrade to 18.04 which resulted in a working distribution without receiving the GRUB installation error during the fresh install.

Comment: The issue seems to be with GRUB 2 failing to install on certain hardware configurations, this should be looked further into.